# Generics структура данных "очередь"

Tags: c#

Реализовать обобщенную (Generics) структуру данных «очередь», позволяющую хранить объекты (ссылочные переменные). Стандартные классы-коллекции .NET не использовать, в качестве внутренней структуры для хранения данных использовать исключительно массивы.

Не понимаю до конца, что от меня требуется. Объясните дубовому.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: нужно сделать generic класс Очередь, внутри которого данные хранить в массивах

Comment: Нужно создать обобщенный(Generics) класс, который обладал бы данной функциональностью: [wiki: очередь](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Очередь_(программирование)) Реализация хранения данных внутри класса через массив.

Answer (score 1):

̶З̶и̶м̶а̶ Сессия близко. 
Обобщенная (Generics) структура данных «очередь» - значит что эта очередь может хранить разные типы данных, тоесть может быть очередь int'ов, string'ов или вообще очередь очередей. Это достигается Generics методами.

Первый ответ из гугла на Ваш вопрос:

```
class SimpleQueue<T> where T : class
    {
        private const int _capasityIncrease = 5;

        private T[] _array;
        private int _count;
        private int _head;
        private int _tail;

        public int Count { get { return _count; } }

        public SimpleQueue()
        {
            _array = new T[5];
            _count = 0;
            _head = 0;
            _tail = 0;
        }

        public void Enqueue(T item)
        {
            if (_tail >= _array.Length)
            {
                Array.Resize(ref _array, _array.Length + _capasityIncrease);
            }
            _array[_tail] = item;
            _count++;
            _tail++;
        }
        public T Dequeue()
        {
            if (_count == 0)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Очередь пуста");
            }
            T item = _array[_head];
            _array[_head] = null;
            _head++;
            _count--;
            return item;
        }
    }
```